# How do I check time range in time range and get redundant time in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

On the assumption that I have 4 variables:

```
@start = 5 AM
@end = 8 AM
@from = 10 PM
@to = 6 AM
```

`@from` and `@to` are called working time. `@start` and `@end` are called morning time.

How do I use SQL to check "working time" in the "morning time"? If it happens, I need to get the redundant time.

I mean from 5AM to 6AM equals 1 hour(s). The following image explains better what I mean:
[image]

Comment: Can eloborate on what you mean by "redundant time"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the pseudo-code is:

```
if ( ( @start < @to ) and ( @end > @from ) )
  return @to - @start
```

Of course you understand that variables must be of `DateTime` type as the two @from and @to span over two days.

**Edited with full example**

```
declare @from datetime = '2015-12-31 22:00'
declare @to datetime = '2016-01-01 06:00'

declare @start datetime = '2016-01-01 05:00'
declare @end datetime = '2016-01-01 08:00'

if ( ( @start < @to ) and ( @end > @from ) )
  select datediff(hour, @start, @to)
```

Result = 1

Comment: your answer is not correct, I try this and I can not get redundant time

Comment: declare start datetime = CONVERT(DATETIME, '05:00')
declare end datetime = CONVERT(DATETIME, '08:00')
declare from datetime = CONVERT(DATETIME, '22:00')
declare to datetime = CONVERT(DATETIME, '06:00')

if ( ( start < to ) and ( end > from ) )
BEGIN
  SELECT to - start
END
ELSE BEGIN
 select 1
END

Comment: You have to declare dates also. It is obvious that @from = 10PM is the previous day.

Comment: and I try declare from datetime = '2016-01-01 05:00'
declare to datetime = '2016-01-01 22:00'

declare start datetime = '2016-01-01 05:00'
declare end datetime = '2016-01-01 08:00'
I get 1020 but I want 3

Comment: @NamNguyen Because the statement `datediff(hour, @start, @to)` gives the difference in full hours. Perhaps you could use `datediff(mi, @start, @to)` instead. This will give the difference in minutes. Please refer to [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) for more information on how to use the `DATEDIFF` function. GL.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much :)